Is there a simple estimate for power transform (Box-Cox, Yeo-Yohnson) transform, that can be computed in O(n)?
So the power transform defines some function $f(\lambda,y)$ and then we're trying to find the $\lambda$ assuming that $f(\lambda|\mathbf{y}) \sim Normal(\mu,\sigma)$.
This is usually done via MLE which then uses some iterative optimization algorithm.
As an implementation, you can call something like scipy.stats.boxcox or sklearn.preprocessing.power_transform.
But this is too slow computationally for what I am doing. I want to run it many many times in a cycle over different data.
So I was thinking maybe there could be an approximate formula which would sacrifice some precision of the full MLE iterative algorithm but give me very quickly at least a semi-reasonable solution (i.e. one that maybe isn't optimal but at least better than no transformation).

you can take a look at Tukey's ladder. It can be thought of as a simplified version of boxcox, but quicker and results in (more) interpretable transformations.

We need more details, because these transforms can be used for various objectives ranging from symmetrizing a data distribution to achieving homoscedasticity.  There exist $O(n\log(n))$ algorithms for each purpose but they are different.

One approach to getting faster but approximate estimates is to randomly subsample the data set
